# Accessing store in another route

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, store

I have this model:

```
App.Game = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr(),
    uri: attr()
});
```

and this route:

```
App.GamesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
      return this.store.find('game');    
  }
});
```

This works fine, calls the backend server, and stores elements in the store (I've checked with Ember inspector). This is the json I return:

{"games":[{"id":"TicTacToe","name":"TicTacToe","uri":"http://localhost:10000/games/TicTacToe"}]}

Now I have this template for 'games' (snipped):

```
{{#each game in model}}
{{#link-to 'games.matchlist' game.id}}{{game.uri}}{{/link-to}}
```

This shows the URI for each game. Now in the games.matchlist route what I would like to do is to search in the store by the game_id received param and get the game URI. The reason is that the server doesn't follow RESTAdapter conventions, and I would like to make a custom AJAX query to that URI myself.
This doesn't work:

```
App.GamesMatchlistRoute = Ember.Route.extend({model: function(params) {
   var store = this.store;
   var game = store.find('game', params.game_id)
   console.log(game);
   console.log("URI: " + game.uri);
```

at this point, game is an object but it's not an instance of my model. It doesn't have a uri attribute. What am I doing wrong? I'm feeling that I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get records without hitting the server and you know you already have it in the store, use this.store.getById('game', ID).

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my mobile, but you need to create a GameAdapter and customize I believe the fetch function. Checkout the docs for adapters on the ember site and you should have your answer.

Your other option is to fetch the data from your server and use `this.store.pushPayload(data)`.

Docs here:  http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload

And the adapter docs here: http://emberjs.com/guides/models/customizing-adapters/

Comment: Not sure if I understand. The Game part works perfectly fine, the server is called, the models are created and I can see them in the store with the correct fields in Ember Inspector. My problem is accessing the store locally in the next route. I assumed that calling this.store.find('game', id) would access that model instance locally.

Comment: I think I'm confused as to what your question is then.... So you have a Route on the server for getting all records, but not just one? If you want to get records without hitting the server and you know you already have it in the store, use this.store.getById('game', ID).

Comment: Yes, that's it. Man, things seems so obvious when you learn them. I didn't know that stores had methods specifically for local queries, I assumed it was all abstracted out for you and that the store cached results for you, so if it had them locally it didn't hit the server. Time to read all the API docs for store.

Comment: BTW, thanks a lot for you help, I'm not sure about the appropriate thing to do with regards to the answer. Maybe you want to convert your comment in an answer so I mark it as the correct one?